# ASP.NET Getting token from another API

Tags: asp.net, token

I have function of getting token(from some ERP) that works in console app, but does not work in ASP.NET app:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var requestBody = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"grant_type", "password"},{"client_id", clientId},{"client_secret", clientSecret},{"username", username},{"password", password}};
    var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestBody);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, requestContent);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(responseContent);
        ret = jsonDocument.RootElement.GetProperty("access_token").GetString();
    }
}
```

Please, help

Comment: _"Please, help"_ - We can't: you haven't told us what the problem is...

Comment: Ver 4.7.2The asp.net page freezing waiting this function that wrapped in Task:  public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
{
    string ret = string.Empty;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
           ...
                ret = jsonDocument.RootElement.GetProperty("access_token").GetString();
            }
        }
}

Comment: What version of ASP.NET is this running in? Is this running in an ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI Controller Action, or a WebForms `Page`? Or even an `.ashx` or `.asmx` handler? Are you using `async`/`await` _safely and responsibly_?

Comment: Ver 4.7.2, I have tried both: default.aspx.cs and generic handler

Comment: Are you aware of the substantial changes you need to make to a WebForms project in order to use `async`/`await`?

Comment: No, please direct me

Comment: Everything you need to know is in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45; **TL;DR:** use `<%@ Page Async="true" %>` with `Page.RegisterAsyncTask` - and you can't use `async`/`await` with any WebForms server-side-events - nor in your `.aspx` render functions.

Comment: and ensure you have `<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />` in your `web.config`